# load a javascript function via string

Tags: javascript

How to load a javascript function via string

```
<div id="test_div">display here</div> // < --display here


<script type="text/javascript">

// string 
var _script=("<script type=\"text/javascript\">

    var disqus_shortname = 'example'; 
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
    }());
</script>");


// write/output the string
document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML= _script;
</script>
```

Comment: dont think it will work and why do you wanna do this???

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want the code to run?  Or do you want it to display in that div?

Comment: @ yes i want to run this code, Does not even show the messagebox document.getElementById("test_div").innerHTML = ("alert(\".\");");

Comment: @Power-Mosfet: If you want to run that script block, just put it in the page, why is it a string?

Comment: I cant, the page where this script supposed to run into is generated form by other script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not allow new lines inside strings, you need escape each new line with a `\`.

```
var _script=("<script type='text/javascript'>\
    var disqus_shortname = 'example';\
    (function () {\
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;\
        s.type = 'text/javascript';\
        s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';\
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);\
    })();\
</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
$('#test_div').click(yourFunctionName)
```

You need to name your function in the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// string 

var _script=("<script type=\"text/javascript\">

var disqus_shortname = 'example'; 
(function yourFunctionName () {
    var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
}());


</script>");
```

I assumed you meant that if you click on the testdiv it should do the function?

Or -- Did you mean you want to load the script dynamically into your webpage?! Ahhhh OK!

Using jQuery Again.

```
$(body).append('<script type="text/javascript">' + YOUR_JAVA_STRING + '</script>');
```